# Confused to prove Group Actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I want to ask about Group Action.

This is the definition of group actions.

Let $G$ be group and $\Omega$ is a set. Group action $G$ on $\Omega$, defined by
if there exist mapping
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma : G\times \Omega &\to& \Omega\\
 (g,\alpha) &\mapsto& g\alpha
\end{eqnarray}
and satisfies the condition

1. $e\alpha = \alpha$ , for all $\alpha\in\Omega$, $e$ identity element on $G$.
2. $(g_1g_2)\alpha= g_1(g_2\alpha)$, for all $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $\alpha \in \Omega$.

Now I want to ask about proving group actions.

Let $S_3$ be symmetric group 
$$S_3=\{e,(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}.$$

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Now I want to check $S_3$ acted on $\Omega$.

Let the mapping

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sigma : S_3\times \mathbb{N} &\to& \mathbb{N}\\
  (a,n) &\mapsto& an.
 \end{eqnarray*}

I check the first axiom,

1. $en=n$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

But I confused about the operation between $e=(1)(2)(3)\in S_3$ and $n\in \mathbb {N}$. How to operate element in $S_3$ and $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Are you sure youre acting on $\Bbb{N}$ and not $\{1,2,3\}$? What does a $3$-cycle do to $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: You need to make clear (to yourself) what you mean by $(a,n)\mapsto an$. What is $(1,3)5$ for example?

Comment: @B.Swan So, I can't acting on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: See Chrysomath's question above.

Comment: @Chrystomath So, I must clearly define the operation. Can I define $(a,n)\mapsto a^n$?, For example, $(1,3)^5=(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)$.

Comment: Also any group action $ G \times X \rightarrow X$ can be understood as a group homomorphism $G \rightarrow S_{|X|}$, so you would have $S_3 \rightarrow S_{|\Bbb{N}|}$, I am not sure whether the second group is even defined.

Comment: Is it possible that you are expected to define that $S_3$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}...$ respectively in the usual way?

Comment: If you use GAP, then you find that $S_3$ does act on $\mathbb{N}$ and that $n^a=n$ for all $n > 3$ and all $a \in S_3$. (GAP uses right actions.)

Comment: A group action of $S_3$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is a group homomorphism $\phi: S_3\rightarrow$ Aut$(\mathbb{N})$. Being a group hom means im$(\phi)$ is a subgroup of Aut$(\mathbb{N})$, and |im$(\phi)|$ divides $|S_3|$. Following these conditions, you can find all the group actions of $S_3$ on $\mathbb{N}$. @B.Swan I think the second group is well-defined. It is all bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ onto itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all. I will understand it.